# App constantly crashing while trying to execute the "+" operator

Tags: android

I am working on an Android project. While trying to make a plus and minus system  for my app, I experienced constant crashes from my phone asking me to report the error. I think this code is very simple, it also does not display any errors in Android Studio, so please have a look. I would like to hear from anyone soon!

```
Button btnPlus = findViewById(R.id.btnPlus);
    btnPlus.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            final EditText input = findViewById(R.id.input);
            int number = Integer.parseInt((input.getText()).toString());
            number = number + 1;
            String full = getString(number);
            input.setText(full);
        }
    });
```

Comment: you should post the error log

Comment: What is getString(...) by the way?

Comment: By the way, **`+`** is an *operator*, not a *command*.

Answer (score 0):

You're inflating your input EditText every time the onClick is called and you're trying getting text from it which is null because you only just inflated it, that's why you can't parse Integer from it or add.

do that:

```
EditText input = findViewById(R.id.input); //inflated only once, earlier

Button btnPlus = findViewById(R.id.btnPlus);
btnPlus.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {         
        int number = Integer.parseInt((input.getText()).toString());
        number = number + 1;

        String full = getString(number);
        input.setText(full);
    }
});
```